# How to store Date and Time in Meteor for range queries?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, meteor

My app needs to create objects that will have a startDate shown in 3 different timezones in browser. The date must also include the exact time. The date should be stored in such a way that it allows for queries "give me all for date between X and Y" and parse it to 3 timezones.

My question is how should I best save (and subsequently retrieve) the date and time so that I can query it later in date ranges, should I maybe use moment.js? What I thought of, is saving the date AND time both in a single unix timestamp in the database, and when reading it just parse it into the date and time with that specific timezone. Is this approach correct, or should I save it as plain javascript Date? Can mongoDB query unix timestamps as date ranges or does it need plain Date objects?

Thanks.

Comment: Forget about UNIX timestamps. A simple `new Date` would work just fine. If you're planning to use `moment` you will probably be using `moment().toDate()` pretty often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you need to know about this can be found [here](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Using-Dates-and-Times-qSQCGFc06gH). The highlights:

- Store dates as JavaScript `Date` objects. They have all the query advantages of integer timestamps, but you don't need to convert them back to `Date` objects to use them.
- Range queries work like so: `Posts.find({creation_date: {$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate}})`
- You should either have the server do the inserts or use the [timesync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync) package to prevent clock skew problems.
- You can use [moment-timezone](https://atmospherejs.com/package/moment-timezone) to format you dates to different timezones. e.g. `moment(date).tz("America/New_York").format('l LT')`