# storing timestamp in meteor mongo collection and then displaying it

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

I have a simple form which when submitted enters data into a meteor mongo collection. I then output the data just submitted into another div, kind of like tweets being submitted and shown in a timeline.

I'd like to store the timestamp of when the user submitted the form into the collection and then display the 'feed' ordered by the timestamp descending, so newest first. I'm currently using moment.js to record the timestamp in the collection and then simply use that timestamp on the output, but it doesnt seem the most efficient way to do this.

I intend to have users in different time zones submitting the form and therefore would like to be able to display the timestamps submitted in UTC ordered by most recent.

Currently I have...

```
Template.form.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var insertPost = {
        timestamp: moment().format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss ZZ')
        // some other stuff as well
    };

 form._id = Posts.insert(insertPost);
```

)};

Then this is being displayed in my post_item.html :

```
<template name="post-item">
    <div>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><small>{{timestamp}}</small></li>
            // some other stuff too
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is this way of storing the timestamp ok? I feel storing it in milliseconds is probably better and then formatting that on the output.

So I can change my form.events code to store

```
timestamp: moment.utc().valueOf(),
```

and this stores in milliseconds since the epoch, but how do I then convert that within the html template to display the timestamp nicely formatted?

Comment: time stored in millis always preferred as it is more general and basic

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store Date and Time in Meteor for range queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393603/how-to-store-date-and-time-in-meteor-for-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

Use moment js to display dates and times in various formats and the atmosphere package has plenty of installs.

http://momentjs.com

https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment

Comment: Sorry I did not read the question properly. I always just use an instance of the Date object with new Date() and format it with moment on the front end. There is also a package to timestamp collections before insert and before update called https://github.com/Sewdn/meteor-collection-behaviours