# Store & Print s date

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I need to store a date, eg "myDate" (with this format dd-mm-YYYY) in mongodb using meteorjs, and when the current date = myDate I wanna display it.
(my project is a list with Note!)

**Template Helpers:**

```
Template.dates_list.helpers({
  dates: function () {
    return Dates.find({}, { sort: { dateTime: +1 } });
  }
});
```

**Template Event:**

```
Template.newDate_form.events({
  "submit .js-save-newDate-form": function (event) {

    var day, dateTime, note;

    day = event.target.day.value;
    dateTime = event.target.dateTime.value;
    note = event.target.note.value;

    if (Meteor.user()) {
      Dates.insert({
        day: day, 
        dateTime: dateTime, 
        note: note
      });
    } //end of if 
    return true; // start the form submit from reloading the page
  }
});
```

**My list template HTML:**

```
<template name="dates_list">
  <tr>
    <th>{{dateTime}}</th>
    <th>{{day}}</th>
    <th>{{note}}</th>
  </tr>
</template>
```

**My Form to insert date**

```
<template name="newDate_form">
  {{#if currentUser}}
    <h4>Push '<b>+</b>' to add new date.</h4>
    <a class="btn btn-default js-toggle-newDate-form" href="#">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <div id="newDate_form" class="hidden_div jumbotron">
      <form class="js-save-newDate-form form-group-sm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dayJob">Day</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dayJob" placeholder="Day format: dd-MM-yyyy" required
          data-fv-notempty-message="The day is required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dateTime">Time</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateTime" placeholder="Time format: hh:mm" required
          data-fv-notempty-message="The time is required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="note">Note</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="note" placeholder="Note" required
          data-fv-notempty-message="Note">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393603/how-to-store-date-and-time-in-meteor-for-range-queries) you should always store your dates as `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports storing Date objects natively, I'd do that and use a template helper to display it the way you want it.  The advantage to this is that querying on Date objects is much easier than string representations of dates.

Here's an example helper:

```
Template.registerHelper( 'humanDate', ( timestamp ) => {
  if ( timestamp ) {
    var time   = moment( timestamp ),
        format = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
    return time.format( format );
  }
});
```

You'll need the momentjs package: `meteor add momentjs:moment` for that to work.

Then you can use the template helper to display your date:

```
{{humanDate dateTime}}
```

Provided that dateTime is an actual date object.  You can create a new Date when you go to insert into your Dates collection with a little refactoring.